# Fill Array of string with interface inforamtion in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i need to fill Fill Array of string with interface inforamtion .

i send server request for return list of role with this code :

```
    public GetRoleClaim(id:number):Observable<string[]>{
  return this.http.get<string[]>('https://localhost:44390/api/Role/GetRoleClaims/'+id,{headers: this.headers}).pipe(
    tap(Claims => this.log("fetch claims")),
    catchError(this.handleError('Error GetRoleClaim', []))
    );
  }
```

it work correct .

after this i give data from component with this code :

```
  this.roleService.GetRoleClaim(this.roleId).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.selectedRole=data
  },
  (error)=>
  swal('خطا',`هنگام دریافت اطلاعات خطایی رخ داده . لطفا با پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید`,'error')
  );
```

. now i need fill this varible `selectedRole:string[];` with `claimValue`  .

the `claimValue` recive from server .

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `this.claims` should be an array of Claims, since `data` variable in your code is also an array of Claims.
"claims" variable definition will look like this, if you had globally defined it in your `.ts` file.

```
claims: Claims[] = [];
```

Now, you can just write a for loop to fill `selectedRole` variable.

```
for (const value of this.claims) {
  selectedRole.push(value.claimValue);
}
```

Assuming selectedRole is defined locally. If it is defined globally then the above code will look like this:

```
for (const value of this.claims) {
  this.selectedRole.push(value.claimValue);
}
```